# How do I install Ubuntu on a USB?

Tags: usb, live-usb

I just want to install the operating system on to a USB and boot into that. The try Ubuntu option isn't what I'm looking for. I always would have to install a driver just to get wifi access and I would like to be able to write and create files that won't be gone as soon as I'm done "trying Ubuntu".

Comment: Try to disconnect all your hard drives and just install from CD to the stick, works for me

Comment: There are two different ways to do it: 1. normal USB install with persistent file storage on the USB drive (i.e. "startup disk"). 2. a "full installation" on the USB which requires a larger USB (>=16GB recommended). What type of installation do you want to do?

Comment: I'm doing this on a macbook and I've been using a bootable USB to mess around with Ubuntu. Can I choose the bootable USB as the drive to install to?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have a large enough USB drive to install Ubuntu on the USB in this way. -- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a full install to USB just like to internal drive.

It is advisable to first disable your internal drive.

Then boot from a Live DVD or LIve USB.

Plug in your target USB and hit Install.
Proceed as with a normal install.

You can also use Something Else to make your first partition FAT32 or NTFS so you can connect to a Windows computer.
In this case use the second partition for / and the third for swap.

You can install proprietary drivers to this type of disk.

Answer (score -1):

There is a "Startup disk creator" option when running the live cd.

When in the "Try Ubuntu" or live cd environment, press your windows key or click the Unity button in the top left corner of the screen and type "startup". "Startup Disk Creator" is one of the options. You'll need a USB drive with 2GB or more free. It installs from the disc.